# “Get involve” or “get involved”?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-patterns, present-participles

I'm little confused.
Which one's grammatically correct?/sound correct?

"I've no obligation to get involve in the situation"
or
"I've no obligation to get involved in the situation"

PS. I think that 1st one sounds good.

Comment: The the form of the verb 'to involve' present in that sentence functions as an adverb. It describes the mode in which 'I have no obligation to get in the situation'. That is why it should take the form of a [participle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle), which is *involved*.

Comment: The first sentence has 'involve' as the target of the verb 'get'. We cannot conclude that it modifies the verb because it is not the participle form. It makes 'involve' look like a noun. It doesn't make sense. Unless there is someone called 'Involve', and the sentence means 'I have not obligation to get [that person called] Involve in the situation'.

Comment: @mama That looks like an answer.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. See [ell.se] Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

***GET INVOLVED*** is the only variant.

According to http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/get:

''***GET***

[linking verb]

:become

// My hands got dirty when I was working in the garden.

// I get very nervous when I have to speak in public.''

After linking verbs we can use only adjectives or participles.